# Regex for two real numbers separated by a space

Tags: java, regex, string

My code is as follows:

```
String realNumber = "[+-]?[\\d]+(?:[\\.][\\d]+)?";
s.next(realNumber + "[\\s]+" + realNumber);
```

Full regex:

```
[+-]?[\\d]+(?:[\\.][\\d]+)?[\\s]+[+-]?[\\d]+(?:[\\.][\\d]+)?
```

This doesn't work.
If I use `s.next(realNumber);` it works fine for a single real number, i.e. `321.1` or `12` etc. The space is the part that seems to throw the mismatch exception.

I have been trying to get this to work for the past hour now >.> Please help!

Patterns that should match:

```
1 1 
1.1 2.1
123 1.123
123.123 1
```

I have got it to work successfully on regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/100, but it still throws an exception in Java.

Comment: Aside: you don't need character classes if there's only one thing in there. E.g. `[\\d]` is the same as `\\d`.

Comment: Try escaping the `-` in the `[+-]` character class. Normally it is used to indicate a range.

Comment: @AndyTurner I find putting square brackets around the character makes it easier to read. Also the `-` in `[+-]` seems to be working fine, you raise a valid point but the `[\\s]` seems to be the culprit in this case.

Comment: I am guessing that `s` is instance of `Scanner` class. By default this class is using whitespace as delimiter, so your regex should describe only one token. It would be simpler to use `nextDouble` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: After you clarify that you want to extract two reals (for just testing, see a more efficient solution below).

To capture and extract reals, use this regex: `"([+\-]{0,1}[\d]+(?:\.[\\d]+)*)"`

- An *ideone* working [**Java example**](http://ideone.com/sFzLLv).
- A *regex101* working example for [**testing**](https://www.regex101.com/r/EwqLNO/8) and [**extracting**](https://www.regex101.com/r/EwqLNO/10).

---

For testing, try this regex: `^(?:[+\-]{0,1}[\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)*\s*){2}$`. This works efficiently for testing!

Comment: This also works for a single real number, there must be exactly two real numbers.
I have an example here: https://www.regex101.com/r/EwqLNO/6

Comment: However the example has an optional space - the space should be compulsory. If i use `\s+` it doesn't work for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChickenFeet Not getting what you want. https://www.regex101.com/r/EwqLNO/8 seems to cover all of your cases.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/EwqLNO/9 should work too - but it still throws the exception in Java.

Comment: @ChickenFeet I added that case to my Java code, it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

So not exactly what I was after, but Java refused to behave. So a work around is as follows:

```
double x, y;
String realNumber = "[+-]?[\\d]+(?:[\\.][\\d]+)?";
x = Double.valueOf(s.next(realNumber));
y = Double.valueOf(s.next(realNumber));
```

Comment: You should have clarified this is what you wanted. I updated my Java code, with a good way to both check and extract real numbers.

Comment: Originally I didn't want to extract two reals. I wanted to return a string, then extract from string using split(" ") method.